# Self-vandalizing deleted answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have noticed that some users, when they delete an answer (for whatever reason), also replace the content with something along the lines of

> <strike>deleted deleted deleted deleted</strike>

I'll refrain from posting a link so as to not embarrass the >100K rep user whose deleted answer inspired this question :-)

Is this an acceptable practice?

I have on occasion deleted my own answers that turned out to be wrong or not as good as others, but have never felt the need to destroy the answer.

Comment: Experienced users are even more sensitive about covering their tracks when they post something dumb. I don't see why the practice shouldn't be acceptable, seeing as deleted content is by definition not supposed  to be seen.

Comment: The content is still there in the revision history, so it's not like you can't see it if you want to, it's just not as visible.

Comment: They're not really destroying anything, since the original content is still going to be visible in the edit history.

Comment: I have seen this in the past on deleted answers. I guess they don't want 10K+ users to see the answer. The edit functionality on a deleted post wasn't meant to be used this way, but since it is deleted it used to sort of virtually write through your answer and destroy evidence. And since it is deleted, they really won't get in trouble for it

Comment: Removing the content has the added benefit of reducing the amount of screen space that the deleted answer takes up (for those who can still view it), which is actually quite helpful for longer answers. It also reinforces the fact to those users that the answer was not relevant and no attention should be paid to it.

Comment: @animuson Although the irony of the situation is that by trying to hide it curious 10k users may end up being *more* likely to want to actually read the answer.

Comment: There is the ever so slight advantage that the answer is less likely to draw a Google hit.

Comment: @HotLicks Aha! Now _that_ is a really valid reason.

Comment: @HotLicks Google's web crawlers don't have 10k rep...and they're not moderators.

Comment: @Servy - But if the answer is useless, there's no point in having Google find it.

Comment: @HotLicks Google *won't* find it.  That's the whole point of my comment.  Google's crawlers won't see deleted posts in the first place, and so couldn't ever direct someone to a deleted answer.

Comment: And they have no sense of irony either.

Comment: I've had an argument once with an OP who was such a dick that I deleted my answer (I don't even remember whether it was right or not). He just didn't deserve my answer anymore and I deleted it and 'destroyed' its contents in a fashion like this. In vain, of course, since OP probably didn't have access to the deleted answer anyway and if he did, he probably could see the revision history as well. Well, anger is a poor adviser, and yet it felt good at the time.

Comment: @Servy that should motivate them to go the last 90% up to 100k :)

Comment: Well, next time we have a moderator election, I'm going to nominate one of Google's crawlers.

Comment: @GolezTrol the whole point of Stack Overflow is that it's a resource of benefit to future users, who have the same questions as the users of today.  In other words, an answer is NOT just for the OP - it's for loads of people who are facing the same issue as the OP, or will face the same issue in days to come.  It's really a shame that you felt compelled to withhold your answer from all of those people, just because one person was obnoxious.

Comment: @DavidWallace I know, right. But I don't think the world will end because of that one answer. I've got over 2000 other answers for the world to enjoy, and if someone else needs that same question answered, they can ask it again, and maybe I will even be the one that answers it again.

Comment: Related: why do deleted answers still appear at all (albeit greyed out). What's the thinking behind not just outright removing them?

Comment: These are examples of the fastest, dumbest gun in the west.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin, I've seen cases where a deleted answer gives context as to how a question evolved (on account of OP editing/commenting history) in a way that otherwise would have been far more tedious to find.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Sure, why not? Nothing of value is lost when you destroy an incorrect answer.

(Note that I'm biased. I've done this a couple of times when I was so far off base that it seemed like I was answering the wrong question entirely.)

Comment: In the Teacher's Lounge (where everyone has mod privileges), the one way to make sure that *everyone* reads a post is to delete it.

Comment: Mostly for the sake of argument: you _could_ be losing some value if the incorrect answer is something that's likely to quickly come to mind to others, and/or might superficially seem correct. Then future visitors wouldn't learn from the wrong-ness. Though that applies mostly to vandalism that _isn't_ accompanied by deletion.

Comment: @Pops - Well if it was that valuable it shouldn't be deleted either.

Comment: @Pops Agreed. There is value in some wrong answers, just not the embarrassingly wrong ones. :)

Comment: I once got into a ko battle with someone who kept undeleting my deleted content. Not sure what to do about that kind of thing.

Comment: @matt Flag for moderators.

Comment: There is also value in destroying an answer: You don't waste other people's time by making them think about something which didn't work. Value in the attempt is only there if it shows how one might approach a problem and why it didn't work in the end - maybe the 100K+ users won't delete that. But if you just misread/-understood the question, why waste other people's time?

Comment: Sometimes, the content of the answer is lost: When it's been destroyed during the grace period.

Comment: @matt You can disown the answer by making it Community Wiki. If you also "destroy" it, the next person's rollback edit will make their name appear as the "most substantial contributor".

Comment: I like lizards.

Comment: A strategy I like is to cover my tracks when I say something dumb by replacing it with something short, correct, insightful, but completely irrelevant. I figure there's way less of a chance of somebody looking at the edit history than if I write "DELETED. DON'T READ ME, I'M A MONSTER."

Answer (score 21):

Incidentally, [Jeff Atwood suggested exactly this strategy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/answers-quickly-deleted-by-owner-should-be-permanently-deleted/117390#117390) years ago, as a way of removing embarrassingly-incorrect answers in a way that wouldn't confuse / annoy 10K users.

Our more experienced / savvy users do this within the 5-minute grace period, thus [fulfilling the spirit of this old feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/answers-quickly-deleted-by-owner-should-be-permanently-deleted) by leaving *no* trace of the original answer, even to 10K users.

Comment: True.  But the 5-min grace period seems to _itch_ when such answers transform into fantastic ones _especially_ after a couple of other reasonable answers show up.

Comment: Not sure why keeping old revisions is mututally exclusive with *edit the body of the now-deleted answer to say something like "oops, I don't know what I was thinking here, my apologies"*  The explanation version is still there, and it's the first thing shown to 10k users.

Answer (score 19):

It's fine; it's just pointless, that's all (given the presence of an Edit History).  The only way you can completely obliterate an answer is if you do it during the first grace period (within 5 minutes of posting).

If a person is really embarrassed about an answer, the right way to deal with it is for the poster to *ask for their name to be disassociated with the post,* although it's hardly worth it for most posts (you'd have to post something really offensive to someone's sensibilities to justify a disassocation).

Comment: Amusingly... I once posted an answer I was embarassed of... Asked the mods to disassociate myself from it... only to promptly have the answer get something like 20 upvotes (on smaller non-SO site so that's not a small # :)

Comment: That's a thing? You can ask for your name to be disassociated with a post?

Comment: @DVK Did you get reputation for all those up-votes even though your name was disassociated?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's required by CC:Wiki.  Try not to make it a habit, though; disassociation is expensive (someone at SE corporate has to do it).  Better to not post the thing that you want no part of in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah I understand, just found it interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @J-Dizzle: you don't, it shows up with a random "userXXXXXXX" name, just like posts which still exist after an author's account is deleted.

Comment: Why does this have to be done by someone at SE Corporate?

Answer (score 13):

As a 10k user, your view of the page changes radically... suddenly there's lots of red stuff on the page.  Especially in questions that have lots of deleted answers (well, thats the red stuff).

[image: deleted stuff]

Thats a lot of vertical scrolling space that has been taken up by one owner deleted answer (there's one more above this one, and two more under it).

By changing the text to something that only takes up one line, your mistake is not quite as obvious on the page and easier to scroll past by other 10k users.  Sometimes its just "<s>deleted</s>", other times its "My answer was just wrong for this case."  Either way, it can save a lot of vertical space that is visible to 10k users.  They can still poke at the edit history if they're curious about the contents, but the random perusal of question doesn't have this big red thing taking up much of the screen.

Comment: Interesting insight.

Comment: That's very, er, courteous of users to do that, but, if this is actually their motivation, then it seems like the real solution would be for deleted answers to be collapsed/hidden/sorted last by default.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that the person who deleted their answer probably posted something very silly and doesn't want anyone to see that they posted it.

The writer of the answer probably came to the decision that there's nothing about the answer worth preserving, and you probably shouldn't worry too much about it.

You don't need the juicy details about whatever the person originally wrote in that box.

Comment: In this case the deleted text was innocuous, as shown by the edit history.

Answer (score -3):

No, it's vandalism.

Stack Overflow has decided that 10k+ users should be able to see deleted answers (whether we agree with this decision or not is irrelevant) but you're violating that decision by defacing posts.

As a 10k+ user, your deleted post is every bit as real and visible as a non-deleted one, so my annoyance at seeing a useless `.....deleted it was wrong.....` block is every bit as real and visible as it would be if you'd done it to a non-deleted post.