# Final (binding) Votes to Close and Delete should trigger a revision to be saved

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, revision-history

As a moderator, I sometimes have to delete bad answers.  Sometimes, [those answers are edited after I've deleted them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275701/a-diamond-moderator-deleted-my-answer-why), and it turns into an episode of ["The Big Bad Moderator"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275701/a-diamond-moderator-deleted-my-answer-why#comment112091_275701).

This doesn't just happen with answers, and it doesn't just happen to moderators.

Anytime the final closure or deletion vote is cast (for moderators, this would be their binding vote), a revision of the post should be generated so that the community knows why the post was closed or deleted. This should happen even if the post is within its initial five-minute grace period for editing.

Alternatively (accomplishes the same goal), [DeDuplicator's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275705/final-binding-votes-to-close-and-delete-should-trigger-a-revision-to-be-saved#comment112118_275705) that once the final (binding) vote is cast for closure or deletion, any new revisions made to the post will trigger a revision change.

This would serve <strike>two</strike> three purposes:

1. It would keep the aforementioned incidents from happening; as anyone could clearly see the state of the post when it was closed/deleted
2. It allows close voters and deletion voters to link to a specific revision they had issues with; so that others could see if those issues were rectified.
3. [As Shog9 points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275705/final-binding-votes-to-close-and-delete-should-trigger-a-revision-to-be-saved?noredirect=1#comment112103_275705): "edits made after closure trigger reopen review. But if there's no edit logged (because the edit was rolled into the original revision) then that doesn't happen"

This probably doesn't happen on other sites as often, but on Stack Overflow I often come across questions or answers that were *just* flagged and take care of the post, and this is sometimes within seconds of the question being posted.  It's actually a little surprising this issue doesn't come up on meta more often.

Comment: It's a bit obscure, but there's another potential advantage here: edits made after closure trigger reopen review. But if there's no edit logged (because the edit was rolled into the original revision) then that doesn't happen.

Comment: Actually, it should not trigger a new revision, but be counted as the last revision for grace-period-purposes (and **only** for that). No need to clutter the revision-history with additional things to keep track of.

Comment: @Deduplicator Do you mean that once that vote is cast; any edits get spawned into a new revision? If so, then we want the same thing; just in slightly different ways.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just wanted to emphasize not adding no-change revisions.

Comment: This would also be solved by [keeping the initial version of a post unconditionally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Only if the original post is the reason it was deleted.  What if they change it twice more in the 5 minute period and the third revision is why it was deleted?

Comment: Not that I'm really opposed to either of these proposals, but that's even more of a fringe case than what happened here. With a five-minute timer ticking, if the post starts out okay, gets edited to something deletion-worthy, gets deleted, and is then edited to something not deletion-worthy, the damage done by the "delete me" version is vanishingly small. I'd think at that point we could just see that the post is now okay, shrug, undelete, and all find something more interesting to do.

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised that the system doesn't save the history of a post if it is edited within 5 minutes. I don't mean to criticise the people who implemented SE, I think they did a great job, but this particular design choice seems strange to me. Why would anyone not want to track changes in their database? Or is the full history of the post saved but just not available in the UI?

Comment: I just had that, someone put `ASFDASDF` as answer, after I flagged it, s\he edited to normal. I am feeling really guilty about that.

Comment: Edits within the first few minutes after a post is created are *ridiculously* common, @ivarni - in the vast majority of cases, tracking them is just a waste of resources. More important though is the embarrassment factor: most folks make stupid little mistakes that aren't caught and corrected until after posting; maintaining a record of these is just discouraging.

Comment: @KugBuBu: If you see that in the future, take a screenshot.  Posting a short correct answer and lengthening it after getting a timestamp added is an acceptable approach to FGITW.  Posting nonsense like asdfasdf is not.

Answer (score 35):

#### Update: declined

I'm declining this, as we just implemented [a more generally-useful change to how grace periods are handled for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876) that I think will suffice here as well... The trick is, you have to leave a comment if you want it to work. That doesn't mean you *always* need to comment when closing or deleting, but in situations that are likely to be controversial you may *want to*.

My suggestions below are still valid as well - one we've implemented, the other I'm still chewing on.

---

#### Original answer

This strikes me as a good idea for moderator accountability - it's all too easy for malicious moderators such as yourself to hand-wave about the grace period right now, when in truth you know that the original answer was 20 paragraphs of beautifully-written prose and example code the like of which has never been seen before.

Or, y'know, the reverse of that.

That said, this isn't a panacea. For anything. It adds a bit of extra information in a fairly critical area, but that doesn't fix the underlying problems:

- If someone is editing and actually *fixing* outstanding issues with their post, then reviewing it is a waste of everyone's time.
- If a post gets closed, there's an explanation of *why* - it's reasonably easy to see whether or not that reason still applies, even if you *can't* see the revision history. But reasons are not always given for deletion, particularly for answers.

Finally, if we do this for *all* deletions it makes [an obscure but valid use-case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers/265757#265757) somewhat more difficult. I don't much like that. If we only do it for 3rd-party deletions, it increases the complexity of this change. Don't care for that either.

I'll dig into this a bit more & see what it'd take to implement. Until then, here are a couple of other options worth considering:

1. **Canned deletion reasons for moderators** (as available in LQ review and the pro forma comments script). This should be optional (no one really needs to comment on blatant spam/nonsense), but when deleting for one of the more common reasons such an option would make it less time-consuming to add a quick note for the author.
2. **Delay on VLQ / NAA flags entering the mod queue**: most of these are already handled by Low Quality review; there's no sense in putting them in front of the moderators unless they cannot or are not being handled by others. Could probably sit on them for a half hour or more without causing any real harm, and save everyone a lot of time and frustration.

Both of these would likely be useful in many less obscure situations.

Comment: I like #2. When I cast VLQ or NAA on an answer, I *hope* it will be handled by reviewers and not by a mod. The workflow is more gradual: some comments (canned or otherwise) are posted, votes are cast meanwhile, and who knows -- maybe the answer gets into shape before the final blow strikes. Unless it's a spam/offensive/abusive post, deletion of an answer does not have to be fast.

Comment: "Finally, if we do this for all deletions it makes an obscure but valid use-case somewhat more difficult." Is edit -> delete really any more difficult than delete -> edit? Or am I missing something with this?

Comment: "Delay on VLQ / NAA flags entering the mod queue" seems a good idea. Most of the time we would like users to deal with what they can deal and only bother moderators with what users can't (as last resource).

Comment: Yeah - right now the order doesn't matter, @Anthony. You can edit then delete, delete then edit, edit then delete then edit some more... It's simply not a concern. If deletion records forced a new revision, then it would be.

Answer (score 5):

I absolutely agree with keeping the evidence of what was voted on.

Unfortunately, the idea is simpler than the implementation.  There's a race condition between:

1. showing a version to the person voting
2. the voter clicking to cast their vote
3. that vote reaching the server
4. ninja edits being accepted by the server

Something AJAXy can help with 4 happening before 2; we already have something that locks out the save edit button when another edit was accepted first.  The issue with 3 and 4 is a true race, however.  And because of the revision merge logic, I don't see a way for the vote message to indicate with enough granularity exactly what revision was voted on, short of sending the entire content again.  But that's no good either, because if the server hasn't kept a copy of the intermediate merged revisions, it can't verify that the voting client hasn't fabricated an objectionable version out of thin air.

Probably the only solution is for the servers to preserve every version, and give each a unique identifier used during voting, but only some get public revision numbers.  Voting can then cause hidden revisions to be given public numbers, and a periodic cleanup could purge old hidden revisions.

Disclaimer: I'm not a developer for the SE platform; I don't have any way of knowing that the server hasn't kept a hidden copy of intermediate revisions, except for commentary by diamond mods that they can't call those up.

Comment: You don't have to go so far as preserving every partial revision. Just adding a minor-revision-counter to the newest revision (thus per-post) would be enough. Ignore the final vote / ask for re-vote on the updated post if they no longer match when receiving on the server to avoid that race-condition.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Or, like my other answer says, maintain that counter per-revision and show it on the edit history view.  Good call.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler and easier possibility is just to separately track "Time of revision creation" and "Time of last edit of revision content".

This would take care of both

- Vote to delete answer, and a ninja edit after deletion makes it look like good content

and

- FGITW posts a placeholder, than 4 minutes later copy+pastes the beautiful answer that took three extra minutes to write, using the post timestamp to (fallaciously) "prove" that it was his work.

because in both cases the public timestamps now show the true ordering of events.

Perhaps even keep a ninja edit count.  That way when a post shows "answers 4 minutes ago; edited 20 seconds ago", viewing the edit history gives some indication of why there is such a discrepancy "Revision 1 (merged four rapid-fire edits)".

Answer (score 1):

Something is not clear to me as you said:

> 1. It would keep the aforementioned incidents from happening; as **anyone** could clearly see the state of the post when it was closed/deleted

As crazy as this sounds : can you please clarify who **anyone** is actually going to be? I thought that only 10K+ can see deleted posts? I am not picking on your wording I just want to make sure I fully understand this.

Comment: For closing, everyone is obviously really everyone. For deleting, everyone is everyone who can see anything at all, as before (everyone if undeleted, mods+10k+owner if not).

Answer (score -25):

The 5 minute "grace period" for editing a post has been around for a very long time.  All I can see that went wrong here is that the user never got a chance to bang his post into shape before those 5 minutes where up.  It was deleted less than a minute after he started.

The proper feature request here, perhaps, is to ask for a warning that you're about to delete a post that wasn't finished.

Comment: If a post really is worthy of deletion/closure, you shouldn't be prevented from casting that vote for 5 minutes.  If someone isn't ready for their post to be evaluated by the community then they shouldn't be posting it.  If they fix the problem with the post, then they can request that the post be restored.

Comment: Nothing to do with "evaluation" of course.  Downvotes doesn't stop a user from posting a good answer.  Deletion does.

Comment: I use the grace period to fix formatting issues; typos; etc. If it was worthy of deletion, it should be deleted. Adding a revision flag just lets the community see what *actually* happened when there is a dispute, as in the linked post. I don't see what harm this feature would do.

Comment: Do you happen to have any reasons _why_ adding a new revision would be bad overall, out of curiosity? To me, this reads more like commentary on the linked question, and does not seem to address why the feature request here is bad. I personally think it would be good if for no other reason that the third point in the current revision/Shog's comment on the question.

Comment: One very good reason to be careful here is that it would somewhat break the ability of authors to permanently remove answers that they realize are inaccurate/unnecessary immediately after posting, @Kendra. It would still be possible by editing and *then* deleting, but that's not as obvious (not that this functionality is exactly obvious to begin with).

Comment: @Shog9 That makes sense. I couldn't think of anything this would break, which is why I asked. Thank you.

Comment: @Shog9 Couldn't we just set a "don't do a revision on self-delete" condition? The main thrust of this is when *other* users close/delete.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sounded like shog was referring to the effects of Hans' proposal of preventing deleting during the grace period, in that such behavior would prevent immediate self deletion.  I don't see any problems with adding a revision entry on self deletion.

Comment: I suggested a warning, not prevention.

Comment: Well, your "warning that you're about to delete a post that wasn't finished" doesn't take into account that _often people never "finish" such a post_; they just post crap and leave it at that. I don't see any real harm in immediate deletion of a post that does not meet the (already fairly low) SO quality standards - at worst it will stop some FGITW behaviour where people post anything just to be first. IMO the grace period should be for fixing _small_ issues, not for transforming a useless placeholder into an actual answer.

Comment: Also "Downvotes doesn't stop a user from posting a good answer. Deletion does" seems like a fallacy - If the user wants to post a valuable answer, deleting their useless placeholder _does not stop them_: they can simply post a new answer. Of course, they might become frustrated they won't get an "enlightened" badge for it because their FGITW tactics failed, and thus choose to not answer the question anymore, but I don't think we should optimize for this case.

Comment: I completely don't get the need to automatically assume that the user does this for ulterior motives.  It could just be, you know, just not haven finished his post.  This guilty-until-proven-innocent attitude is basically what the OP is complaining about.

Comment: Not finished with an answer? Don't hit "post your answer." Problem solved.

Comment: @Shog9: There is no such ability of authors to "permanently remove answers that they realize are inaccurate/unnecessary immediately after posting".  As soon as they hit submit, they've released it into the wild under CC BY-SA license.  Removal from the SE servers is not the same as "permanent removal".  It could be saved all over the place in browser caches or screenshots, and those copies are licensed for resharing.