# Really, really delete a bad answer you wrote

Tags: feature-request

Every once in a while, I am in too much of a rush and misread the question, and then post a terrible answer as a result. An example would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704686/8946).

Now, maybe it's mostly pride, but it's also clutter. The answer is useless, but my stupid mistake is memorialized for all (10K+) users to see forever.

Could we not have a mechanism for deleting (perhaps only negatively voted) answers permanently? At least for the author of an answer.

I've tried flagging and requesting this before and nothing was done -- the answer remained.

Comment: We all make mistakes and nobody remembers a deleted answer, *I hope :P*

Comment: I'm usually editing such to "irrelevant stuff" or alike.

Comment: Do you *really* need to try to prevent anyone from ever knowing you made a mistake.  You should be able to admit that you made a small mistake and just move on without needing to actively prevent anyone from ever figuring out that you're not perfect.

Comment: "Now, maybe it's mostly pride, but it's also clutter." The clutter is actually meant as punishment for anyone reaching 10k rep ;)

Comment: Read this, get answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225986/what-are-the-conditions-for-a-dissociation-and-how-does-it-impact-the-post-ban-s/225990#225990

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers

Comment: There is an obvious solution to this problem in most cases - just stop trying to be the FGITW. If you're not rushing so fast to be first to answer, you might have more time to read the question properly in the first place. I'd much rather post a better answer than a poor "I got here first" version.

Answer (score 10):

When you posted the content to SE you licenced away your right to have that content shared by anyone with the whole world.  If SE, or anyone else, really wants to share that content, they can.

There's also the issue of users rage quitting and trying to delete a bunch of valuable content out of spite.

If the answer is simply useless, and has already been deleted, then you're going to spend more effort trying to get it hard deleted than whatever problems it would cause by being visible to 10k+ users.  Just leave it alone.

Comment: There are two situations in which hard-deletion might happen: You didn't have the right to post it, and the holder of those rights insists to SE. Or it contains sensitive information (which you edited out), and you flag it. In both cases, SE does it, not even the mods are that trusted. Though in both cases it will probably only be a purging of the revision-history.

Answer (score 5):

Even if you really, really, really wanted to delete something, and it was removed entirely from SE, it would still live in:

- The Internet Archive (www.archive.org)
- SE Data Dump, unless it was deleted before it made its way into a data dump.  Since that's automatically downloaded by many users, it could easily hang around in that way forever.
- The memories of those who read it.

Don't worry about really bad answers.  Delete them (so they are blue) and nobody will think less of you.  We've all posted that bad answer from time to time.  Except Jon Skeet, anyway.

Comment: I've seen Jon post incorrect answers and then delete them.

Comment: @Servy: Proof or it didn't happen. ;-) Anyway, that was probably his evil twin.

Comment: I should realize humor isn't compatible with this site...

Comment: It's unlikely Servy misunderstood the humour in last paragraph, Joe; that even *the #1 user of the site*
 occasionally has to delete an answer (and is fine with it being theoretically visible to other 10k+ers) strengthens your case even further - and hence, is worth pointing out.

Comment: Normally when one uses obvious humor to make a point, it isn't necessary to point it out, as it sort of ruins the humor...

Answer (score -8):

Ín name of keeping the site clean and usable I would actually propose that users can delete their own negatively scored answers (aka useless answers) at any time permanently if they want that. As a consequence I would also ask for the consent of SE towards this.

If not yet existing such a feature should be made available to everyone.

Not seeing really bad answers or questions removes clutter and makes the other (better) answers slightly more standing out.

Positively or neutrally scored answers have to stay though.

One could argue that even failed answers may provide some value (although probably very little) and it's not that important because negatively scored answers are sorted below anyway but still weighing everything I think it's better to get rid of them.

Comment: Deleted answers are already shown after all non-deleted answers, and have a red background to make it very clear visually that the answers have been deleted.  Such answers aren't going to be drawing attention away from other content.  The **vast** majority of users also can't see deleted answers anyway, so it impacts a very small percentage of users.

Comment: The only constraint on users deleting their own answers is "if it is accepted."  All other answers can be self deleted (there's even a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) or [two](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) for it). Positive answers can be wrong too.

Comment: @MichaelT Keep in mind the distinction between soft deletions and hard deletions.  You're talking about soft deletions; the question and this answer is advocating that people should be able to *hard* delete their own answers.

Comment: @Servy indeed... permanent deletions take an act of SE to do so (I've seen it happen from time to time when there are special circumstances). Hard deletions would make recovering from self-vandalized answers difficult (and violate the license that you've granted SE and the community on the content that was posted).

Comment: @MichaelT I don't think it violates any license. You give them the right to use the content, but they don't have the duty to keep the content. So as long as they agree to your wish every content can be hard deleted. If they don't agree of course nothing one can do. However asking for it and accepting the request is not a violation of the license.

Comment: @Trilarion You're not prohibited from *asking* for the content to be hard deleted.  They have every right to refuse and keep the content anyway.  The point is that you don't have the right to force them to delete it.  You gave up that right when you posted the content.

Comment: @Servy I never challenged this. I just ask them to always delete (hard) negatively scored answers by themselves upon the authors request. If they don't want that, nothing I can do. I'm fully aware of the license terms having used CC-BY-SA myself many times.

Comment: @Trilarion "You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content" - note that soft deletes are also necessary for situations where it is necessary to identify a pattern of misuse of the resources (spam, libel, or other fraudulent postings) and helps other automated systems (e.g. post bans) that would lose important data in the event that material is hard deleted.

Comment: @MichaelT I know all that. Maybe you should point me to a place where I said anything to the contrary. Otherwise we might continue for a long time without understanding each other. To make it more clear I edited the question.