# Can the 5 minute grace period cause data loss?

Tags: discussion, revision-history

Apparently, if an extra edit happens less than 5 minutes after the previous edit, no new revision is created.

Consider the scenario when a user asks a new long descriptive question, and a few seconds later the same user (or another user) edits the question, but makes a mistake and deletes the whole question, leaving only a few words, in the editor and submits it. Does it not cause data loss?

Comment: Those voting to close as a duplicate should note that [this question was altered fairly significantly after being posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/296610/revisions).

Comment: @Shog9 does those voters(close voters/ vote casters on the question) get notification when a closed question improved?

Comment: No they do not.

Comment: Is this getting downvoted because of the duplication?

Comment: @ali don't worry about downvote.You may got them before reopen the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another user's edit will end the grace period. So it is not possible to lose data that way.

Your own edit *might* be rolled in, so it is possible for you to "lose" data that way. This is expected and [by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers/265757#265757).